# Removing duplicate items from array but merging duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays

This is one of those situations where I'm sure that there's a simple solution, and I need help getting to it.

Suppose we're dealing with three phone numbers: *home (h)*, *office (o)* and *mobile (m)*. We need to avoid displaying duplicate phone numbers to the end user.

To better explain, here are three sample cases (in PHP):

Case 1:

```
$phone = array(
    'h' => '212-555-1212',
    'o' => '212-555-1212',
    'm' => '212-555-1212'
);
```

Should yield:

```
212-555-1212 (h,o,m)
```

Case 2:

```
$phone = array(
    'h' => '212-555-1212',
    'o' => '212-555-1234', // different
    'm' => '212-555-1212'
);
```

Should yield:

```
212-555-1212 (h,m)
212-555-1234 (o)
```

Case 3:

```
$phone = array(
    'h' => null,
    'o' => '212-555-1234',
    'm' => '212-555-1212'
);
```

Should yield:

```
212-555-1234 (o)
212-555-1212 (m)
```

I have tried using various `case` statements, by checking for each scenario, but it's complicated by the fact that some values might be empty.
I have also tried using overly-complicated `if/elseif/else` conditions, but again, it's extremly inelegant.

My best efforts resulted from using `array_filter` to remove empty elements from the array and the using `array_unique` to remove duplicates, but then I lose the H/O/M key:

```
$phone = array_filter(array_unique($phone));
```

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first flip the array. Create a new array with the phone number as the key. Something like this:

```
$numbers = [];
foreach($phone AS $type => $number) { 
    $numbers[$number][] = $type;
}
```

Now you have a `$numbers` array, with unique phones, and an array of types for each one.

To display your output then:

```
foreach($numbers AS $number => $types) {
    echo $number . " (" . implode(",",$types) . ")";
}
```

I've wrapped this up as a real quick function, and run all three of your cases through. You can see the code and output here:

https://3v4l.org/U6c4K

Comment: Creative thinking! Thank you, I'll keep this one in my toolbox.